# "pacman -Syu" not working: invalid PGP key

Tags: pacman-package-manager

I'm trying to do a full system upgrade using `pacman -Syu`. It says:

```
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/turbulence-0.3.5-1-any.pkg.tar.xz is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)). 
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n]
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: There is [a bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/75574) about this in the pacman bug tracker.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are tons of topics out there that say you should edit the `pacman.config` file and remove the PGP key checks entirely but it's not a good idea.

simply run this command and wait for refreshing your keys by downloading them from the servers:

```
$ sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys
```

and then proceed with you full system upgrade `sudo pacman -Syu`

Comment: This fixed everything for me. It's just as easy as telling pacman to ignore key checks, but is more secure, so it seems silly to *not* use this solution.

Comment: For me any of those solutions didn't help, so shortcut to bypass integrity checks is changing `/etc/pacman.conf` SigLevel to `SigLevel = Never TrustAll` Do this at your own risk! :-D

Answer (score 17):

You may also be interested in running `pacman-key --populate` if the keys are massively out of date or if the other given answer of `pacman-key --refresh-keys` does not work in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes starting from zero (cleaning PGP keys first) is a good option :

```
rm -rf /etc/pacman.d/gnupg  
pacman-key --init 
pacman-key --populate
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when using a (ridiculously) outdated Arch version.

In case anyone else runs into this while using Docker, you can try downloading a fresh image (`docker pull archlinux`) in lieu of directly refreshing the keys.

I think this is useful because the sibling answers did not work for me.